# Book where a woman with martial arts skills goes back to king Arthur's time

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I'm looking for the title of a book which I read in 2001 in Australia. I had to leave it there when I returned to Germany.

The story details are as follows:

- A young, relatively small woman is transported to king Arthur's time, meets him and a few knights right away and is drawn into a fight.
- With her Taekwando(?) skills she bests one of his knights.
- She ends up teaching her martial art to all of them.
- Somewhere in the book people in present time are wondering how an Asian martial art came to England that early in time.

**Please identify this book.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is [The Ancient Future Trilogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ancient_Future_Trilogy), by Traci Harding. The first book is called [*The Dark Age*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1961495.The_Dark_Age?from_search=true).

> Prince Maelgwyn of Gwynedd and his band of knights stumble across this mysterious woman dressed in jeans and a leather jacket. Believing she is the witch of the stones, they threaten to kill her. Rising to her own defence, Tory challenges the Prince's champion to unarmed combat. With her superior fighting skill she easily overwhelms the warrior, winning the admiration of the Prince, and changing the course of British history forever

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, thanks.