# Fantasy series three books, Australian woman on vacation, travels back in time to Welsh castle, Tae Kwon Do

Tags: story-identification, books, soft-sci-fi

Looking for title of a series of 3 (to 5) books, probably Australian author.

In the first book:  A young Australian woman (and Tae Kwon Do expert) vacations in Britain, shortly after the death of her twin brother.  She sleeps inside a ring of standing stones (possibly at the summer equinox?) and ends up in medieval(?) Wales.  She encounters a group of warriors on horseback, managing to take down one of them in unarmed combat.  She is taken to a castle, where she starts training the young lord and his men in martial arts.  Eventually they become lovers and marries.

There are some prophetic dreams and a traitor, ending with the woman (almost?) miscarrying - in any case they eventually have at least one child.

She eventually returns to her own time, and discovers that in this new world by a strange coincidence, Wales developed a very similar martial arts style to that of the Far East, baffling scientists.  I also think her brother is now alive.

I may be on the second book, but I also seem to remember a possessed friend and a floor open to lava or something similar...

In the later books (which I haven't really read), she possibly travels to the future (from where she originally started).  There is also a base in the Australian desert where several antiquates and relatives - including her supposed to be dead many hundred years ago son - have set-up a base to basically save the Earth.

I think the first book got a circle of standing stones on the cover; the second similar but possibly with lightning; and the third a space station looking like the standing stones.

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64448/book-where-a-woman-with-martial-arts-skills-goes-back-to-king-arthurs-time

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sounds a lot like *[The Dark Age](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?902935)* by Traci Harding (indeed an Australian author) the first book in *The Ancient Future* trilogy.

The protagonist is Tory Alexander, a woman who has a black belt in Tae-kwon-doh, and somewhat improbably is fluent in Brythanic, who gets transported to 6th century Wales while spending the night at a ring of standing stones when her car breaks down. From the cover blurb:

> But across the vortex of time and space, she is being watched. The
> Merlin knows of the legend Tory is to become, and through the wisdom
> of the Old Ones, teleports her back to the Dark Age.
>
> Prince Maelgwyn of Gwynedd and his band of knights stumble across this
> mysterious woman dressed in jeans and a leather jacket. Believing she
> is the witch of the stones, they threaten to kill her. Rising to her
> own defence, Tory challenges the Prince's champion to unarmed combat.
> With her superior fighting skill she easily overwhelms the warrior,
> winning the admiration of the Prince, and changing the course of
> British history forever.

The cover art of the first book does show a ring of standing stones, as does the second book "An echo in time: Atlantis", while the third book, "Master of reality: the gathering" indeed has a space station resembling standing stones.

[image: Book covers for "The Ancient Future" trilogy]

Comment: "gets transported to 6th century Wales while spending the night at a ring of standing stones when her car breaks down" sounds a lot like the premise of _Outlander_. Not sure which came first. No implication of one stealing from the other implied or intended.

Comment: Yep, that's the one!  Thanks for the answer!